# Know if an item overlaps the parent

Tags: qt4, qml, qt-quick

I have a QML item that could in some cases overlap the parent item and exceeds its width/height. How can I know if it overlaps the parent item? I think I should use something like mapFromItem/mapToItem but I have no idea about how it could work